# Google serverless VPC connector does not access GCE instance with multiple network interfaces

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine, serverless, google-vpc

Is there anyway I can connect the Cloud Functions with a **VPC connector on default network** to a GCE instance with multiple network interfaces where **nic0 is someother network** and **nic1 is default network**?

So I have a GCE instance with multiple network interfaces.

`nic0 is someother network`

`nic1 is default network`

I made a serverless VPC connector on **default** network. And used that connector with Google Cloud functions to connect to the GCE instance.

The problem is that when network interfaces are swapped i.e. **nic0 is default network** and **nic1 is someother network**, then VPC connector connects successfully and cloud functions can reach the GCE but when **nic0 is someother network** and **nic1 is default network** then cloud functions cannot reach GCE.

I tried the following things:

1. I tried swapping the network interfaces i.e. default to nic0 and it works but i need nic0 for **someother** network to connect to another external server and so **default** is on nic1.
2. I tried making firewall rules but apparently they are not needed in this scenario as I already have the necessary rules setup.
3. I tried making a VPC connector on the **someother** network so it could connect to nic0 but that does not work too. VPC connector should be on default network.

**Note: I have the correct IAM permissions setup as I've successfully connected Cloud functions to GCE instance with only default network.**

Comment: You mentioned nics being in different networks. Are these VPCs or subnets in the same VPC? If different, are they regional but routed between them? Also, is the nic configuration compatible with the VPC CIDRs when swapping?

Comment: Both nics have different VPC networks which also means that their subnets are in their own respective VPC networks. But both VPC networks are in the same region and there are firewall rules that allow traffic between them i believe i.e. the **default network** has a route defined to the **someother network**.
NOTE: I'm not an expert on networking so I'm sorry if I sound like a newbie Or if theres something not clear OR if the jargon used is wrong.

Comment: Hi, just trying to get details to repro ;). So, when you swap the nics, are you also changing the addresses to match the respective VPC CIDRs? When swapped, are you still able to reach your VM services in both VPCs using other clients but GCF?

Comment: Thats a good point. I am changing the addresses to match the respective VPC CIDRs but I didn't try reaching using other clients after swapping. I'll check that and get back to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without further configuration, secondary network interfaces [only provide access to the immediate subnet they are attached to](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#i_am_not_able_to_connect_to_secondary_interfaces_internal_ip), this includes serverless VPC connectors, as they are by their very nature a different subnet than the one your instance is attached to.

To get around this, you need to create a static route in the operating system on the instance where the secondary interface is located.  This will obviously vary based on your operating system, but on Debian-9 you can set this up with this command:

```
sudo ip route add [MY_CONNECTOR_SUBNET] via [ETH1_DEFAULT_ROUTER] dev eth1
```

Where ETH1_DEFAULT_ROUTER is the .1 address of your ETH1 subnet, and MY_CONNECTOR_SUBNET is the CIDR-format /28 subnet the connector is configured to use (e.g. something like 10.50.1.0/28, but it will depend on how you set up your connector).

Of course, this doesn't persist it at boot, as that is also an OS-specific configuration, but it should give you an idea if this is the problem for you.

Also, there isn't really anything special about the 'default' network -- its just an auto-created auto-mode network, and there isn't any reason this shouldn't have worked when you had the connector attached to the nic0 "someother" network.  The only thing happening here that is 'special' is that nic0 gets the default route for all traffic out of the VM, and therefore won't need a static route added to access a Serverless VPC Connector on the same network.